# Bugzilla 4.0 Post Bug Error

Tags: linux, bugzilla

I have installed Bugzilla 4.0 on Ubuntu 10.04.4. We have multiple instances of Bugzilla for each project and postfix is being used behind to send emails.
 Recently we created a project and created the users. In those users for only one user when he tries to post a bug the below error is being displayed.

```
Bugzilla has suffered an internal error. Please save this page and send it to bugzilla.admin@abc.com with details of what you were doing at the time this message appeared.

URL: http://12.34.56.78/bigbugz/xyz2225/relogin.cgi
There was an error sending mail from 'bugzilla-daemon@' to 'jango@abc.com':Can't call method "address" on an undefined value at lib/Email/Send/SMTP.pm line 25.

Traceback:

 at Bugzilla/Mailer.pm line 186
    Bugzilla::Mailer::MessageToMTA(...) called at /var/www/bigbugz/xyz2225/relogin.cgi line 168
```

Can you please help me out to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by replacing SMTP to Sendmail in data/params file under the field '***mail_delivery_method' => '**Sendmail*****'